# Magento Custom Module Grid Serializer

Tags: magento

I am working on a custom Magento module to enter Composer information (name, bio, birth, death, etc.) and associate products (songs) with the composer. The module contains two tabs, one for the general info and the other for a list of the products (songs). The association should work exactly as the functionality of Related Products, Up-sells, and Cross-sells in the Product editing page. I feel like I've been running around in circles on a few points in regards to paging through the available songs and selecting and saving the entries. It's mainly dealing with the Grid Serialization. I've looked through as many resources as I can find, including several tutorials, without any luck:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/

I've posted the relevant files at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a5fe255bfccce2a91180) and would appreciate any feedback or discussion. The files have a lot of material commented out from trying various solutions but they may prove useful in terms of thought process. Certainly available to post any other files that may be relevant.

Comment: Please cut your code down to a Minimal Working Example that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13309/146) is exactly what you need. I know that single link answers are not very appreciated but the answer is kind of long to replicate in here.

You can also use this [module creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9) to create you module (also available on [magento connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-modulecreator.html)). It has an UI that let's you create the modules in a similar way with how you create a table using phpMyAdmin. For each entity you create in your module you have the ability to say "Link many to many with products". This will create the the relation table between products and your entity and the second tab in the admin where you can choose products that are associated with your entity. Exactly like the products in the categories or like related products.

---

I admit that I'm the developer of the extension, but this should not be considered as spam since the extension is free and I get no profit out of it.

Comment: +1 Marius, exactly what I was looking for. The extensions is working perfectly for my needs and provides an excellent learning tool if you sit down and read through the code. Much appreciated.